# Xcode 7.1 crash when create new project/file

Tags: xcode

I'm experiencing a crash in Xcode 7.1 when I try to create a new Project on  Mac OS X 10.11 (15A178w)

#### Crash Log:

```
Process:               Xcode [69405]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.1 (9079)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9079000000000000~8
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       813804225
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [69405]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-11-11 16:09:56.301 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A178w)
Report Version:        11 

Time Awake Since Boot: 110000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       17000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7f87e7885220> from <NSButton: 0x7f87e942fe00>
ProductBuildVersion: 7B91b
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSOpenPanel setAccessoryViewDisclosed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f87e9669840
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7f87e7885220> from <NSButton: 0x7f87e942fe00>
```

Does anyone know what causes this issue & how I can fix it?

Comment: You have tried to delete "Xcode" and install it again?

Comment: No, I haven't try reinstall

Comment: Very strange. Try to open Disk Utility and repair the disk. If this does not work my solution and Restart Macbook, and enter Recovery Mode,
and choose Reinstall Mac OS X.

Comment: @Diego what kind of suggestion is that? Do you have any point supporting you to ask him to wipe his hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me, and I tried installing the Xcode 8 beta 2, to find if the problem was with my XCode 7. The issue happened again. Just tried to recollect how it happened first time, and it came to my mind that I had actually tried to create a git repository online, using my gitHub account, from XCode. When creating a new project, Xcode provides option to choose to create a local git repo or an online repo. I'd opted for an online repo option, and ever since i got this issue.

Finally I tried turning off the WiFi, and Voila!!! There it runs, just fine!

Once the project is created and built fine, I turned WiFi back on, and Thank God, things are back to normal!

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: No, I didn't have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the same: create an empty project (with main interface set to LaunchScreen) and it crashed. Doing the same with main interface set to main works. Probably, in the first case, you should define your LaunchScreen ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue it was very irritating , what i did is i just cleared derived data for the project in which i was facing the issue and it worked for me!! :)